# jQuery-UI Dialog

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm new to jQuery, and now I want to use jQuery-UI Dialog to show a nice message with long text to the user. The problem is that I want that every row in my Html table will have a "More details" link that will cause the jQuery Dialog window to open with the text from this specific row.
What should I add to the code that came with the jQuery-UI Dialog example? :

```
            // Dialog           
            $('#dialog').dialog({
                autoOpen: false,
                width: 600,
                buttons: {
                    "Ok": function() { 
                        $(this).dialog("close"); 
                    }, 
                    "Cancel": function() { 
                        $(this).dialog("close"); 
                    } 
                }
            });
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're going to want to bind an event handler to each row (or, better, use ".delegate()" on the table), probably for "click":

```
$('#yourTable').delegate("tr", "click", function() {
  var $row = $(this);
  // setup code here, and then:
  $('#dialog').dialog('open');
});
```

In that handler, you'll want to pull stuff from the row and populate something in the dialog to reflect the table row contents.

*edit* — If you want only clicks in specific columns to bring up the dialog, you can just change the selector in the call to ".delegate()".  For example, you might give the clickable `<td>` cells class "info", so that you could then do this:

```
 $('#yourTable').delegate("td.info", "click", function() {
   var $cell = $(this), $row = $cell.closest('td');
   // setup code ...
   $('#dialog').dialog('open');
 });
```

Comment: Sound good. How will I make it so the deligate will work only when clicking column 5 in the table?

Answer (score 0):

An alternative is to use the tiny jTruncate plugin.

http://blog.jeremymartin.name/2008/02/jtruncate-in-action.html

Comment: What does that have to do with showing dialogs? *edit* oh I see - you're saying that it could be used to shorten the "nice message with long text."